# Calling an Oracle Stored Procedure in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures, sys-refcursor

Here's how I'm able to execute my stored procedure through SqlDeveloper

```
var p refcursor;
exec DMG.Getstudentids(12342343,:p);
print p;
```

Output

```
P
-----------
STUDENT_ID
-----------
23432425
54353455
```

Now I'm trying execute the stored procedure the same way but in Java. Here's my code and I'm missing something about the input/output parameters or their datatypes.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call DMG.Getstudentids(?,?)}");
cs.setFloat(1, 12342343);
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.OTHER);
cs.execute();
List<Integer> result = (List<Integer>) cs.getArray(2);
```

I get the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
```

I think I'm missing something fundamental here. Anyone see where I'm failing? Thanks.

Comment: See here - http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call DMG.Getstudentids(?,?)}");
cs.setFloat(1, 12342343);
cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.executeQuery();
ResultSet resultSet=cs.getObject(1);
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(resultSet.next()){
 result.add(resultSet.getInt(STUDENT_ID));
}
```

`Note :` Since the `procedure` is returning `refcursor`, you need to register `OracleTypes.CURSOR` as output parameter.

Nother thing to note is you need to catch the whole dataset`(refcursor)` into `Result Set`, iterate it and put the extracted value into `List`.