# Create an endpoint to invoke the procedure

Tags: java, crud, procedure

Using Java, I have built many CRUD applications but I need an idea of how to create an endpoint to invoke the procedure in TempDB -- for development I can create a small procedure in dev env and invoke it from java.

I am using SQL developer, Oracle database, and Java language. I tried to look at other docs as well but could not find any article related to that. Can anyone point me to the correct link?

**UPDATE:**

I wrote one simple stored procedure in SQL Developer. I get an error

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETWORKFLOWINPUTRECORDS 
 IS
  R_DATA reorg_automation_workflowinput%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO R_DATA FROM reorg_automation_workflowinput where REORG_ID = 'S-CFO-FULL-65';
END GETWORKFLOWINPUTRECORDS;
```

When I run the below query, it gives only 1 result but in the procedure, I am getting the above error.

```
SELECT *  
FROM reorg_automation_workflowinput 
WHERE REORG_ID = 'S-CFO-FULL-65';
```

Let's resolve this issue and then we can move forward with building API for calling a stored procedure.

**UPDATE 2**

It is fetching empty result while running this procedure. Any suggestion on this?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GETWORKFLOWINPUTRECORDS 
 AS
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
open c1 for
  SELECT * FROM reorg_automation_workflowinput;
END GETWORKFLOWINPUTRECORDS;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want a REST endpoint which causes a stored procedure to be executed when a request hits the endpoint? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @tgdavies yes I mean that

Comment: Which part of doing that are you having trouble with?

Comment: @tgdavies I have updated my question. Can you please check it

Comment: This link gives example calling oracle stored procedure. It's not exactly with REST but you can modify with REST. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351192/calling-an-oracle-stored-procedure-in-java